# How can I get a vue component's contents(modal window) by clicking a button which is contained in another vue component?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vue-component

I am trying to sort my basic Vue application into components. I have a product listing, each contains some information and a button. The button(more details button) when clicked opens a modal window that contains that specific product's further information. I have a product listing component and a modal window component in Vue. I am not really sure how I could call the modal window component containing that particular product's info from the product listing when the user clicks the button. I would appreciate some help with this. This is what I have so far:

**PRODUCT LISTING COMPONENT**

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="nested" v-for="product in products">
            <div class="one"><span>{{product.Name}}</span></div>
            <div class="two"><img src="src/assets/shape.svg" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;"><span>-{{ product.Reduction_percentage }}%</span></div>       
            <div class="three"><span>{{ product.Short_Description }}</span></div>
            <div class="four"><b-btn v-b-modal="'productModal'" @click="chooseProduct(product)" product_item="'product'">More details</b-btn></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
        products: [
              {id: 1, Name: 'Product 1', Reduction_percentage: 30, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 2, Name: 'Product 2', Reduction_percentage: 33, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 3, Name: 'Product 3', Reduction_percentage: 23, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 4, Name: 'Product 4', Reduction_percentage: 77, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
              {id: 5, Name: 'Product 5', Reduction_percentage: 99, Short_Description:"Something", Description:"Something more"},
          ]
    }
  },
methods: {
            chooseProduct: function (product) {
            this.chosenProduct = product
        },
}
</script>
```

**MODAL WINDOW COMPONENT**

```
<template>
<b-modal id="productModal" v-if="chosenProduct" :title="chosenProduct.Name">
            <div class = "inner-container">
                <div class = "inner-nested">
                    <div class="inner-one"><br> {{chosenProduct.Description}}</div>
                    <div class="inner-two">
                        -{{ chosenProduct.Reduction_percentage }}%</div>  
                    <div class="inner-three"> <button>Buy Now</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-modal>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 3 categories of component communication:

1. **Parent to Child**: [Use Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)
2. **Child to Parent**: [Use emits](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201)
3. **Any to any**: Use either an event bus (not recommending) or add
   [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) to your project to handle your app state

Comment: I have one root component and then its child components, I am basically referring to child content(modal window) being called by another child component(product listing). I am still a bit unclear here. :(

Comment: So it is the 3rd case. You could use a combination of the first two to wire this up (yes a bit annoying).  Fratosiles answer also works, but only for a smaller project, it is not the cleanest way. If your project is small use his answer for now. I think you should go for Vuex in any other case. That will then store your chosenProduct variable for all components to see.

Answer (score 0):

Event should work, in list component try something like:

```
this.$root.$emit('open-modal', chosenProduct)
```

And in modal component

```
this.$root.$on('open-modal', (chosenProduct) => {
  // open modal...
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I added this to my Product listing component, 
```methods: {
      chooseProduct: function (product) {
                this.$root.$emit('open-modal', chosenProduct)
        }
}
```
I am not sure where I should be adding in the other line in the modal component. Also, the product data is contained in the product listing component, right?

Comment: Maybe something like ```this.$root.$on('open-modal', (chosenProduct) => {
    this.chosenProduct = chosenProduct
}) ```